# Assuming d is an “empty” object in scope, say:

Tags: javascript

Assuming d is an “empty” object in scope, say:

```
 var d = {};
```

…what is accomplished using the following code?

```
[ 'zebra', 'horse' ].forEach(function(k) {
    d[k] = undefined;
});
```

Comment: That will result in `d` being updated in place to `{ zebra: undefined, horse: undefined }`. It's just adding keys with undefined values to the object.

Comment: why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: I want learn from anyone because I can get the differences answers

Comment: you're not asking "why" though.. you're asking for an output. your interpreter/browser/debugger is the one that question should be addressed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you want to learn, as you mentioned in comments, here are my thoughts on this. Of course, as ljbc1994 pointed out, the result is just:

```
{ zebra: undefined, horse: undefined }
```

So what's accomplished with this, i.e., how could something like this be useful? I think that really depends on the context and especially what the array signifies. If the array is indeed hard-coded into the code, then this is probably not very useful. But I've used this pattern in cases where the array was dynamic, e.g., retrieved from an API or database. In that case, there could be duplicates in the array, and after running the above I would be able to get a duplicate-free list of elements from `Object.keys(d)`, e.g.:

```js
var d = {};
[ 'zebra', 'horse', 'orange', 'zebra' ].forEach(k => d[k] = undefined);
console.log(Object.keys(d));
```

Another application of this is for O(1) access, i.e., indexing the content of the array. If the array is long, and we need to repeated check for existence of an element within it, then transforming this first into an object (which is indexes by key by the JS engine) pays of handsomely when doing the repeated lookups. Run the snippet to see for yourself.

```js
// create a large test array
const large = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { large.push( i*i ); }

// do a lot of "is element of" tests
console.time('using array');
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { large.includes( i*i ); }
console.timeEnd('using array');

// do the same using an index
console.time('using object');
const d = {};
large.forEach(k => d[k] = undefined);
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) { d.hasOwnProperty( i*i ); }
console.timeEnd('using object');
```